# $page =$_GET["page] (an other post)

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP and i block on a problem. I read posts about this issue but i still do not understand.

This is my code (from index.php):

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
$page = $_GET['action'];

if ($page == "operation" && $action == "liste"){
     include("operationForm.php");
   }
if ($page == "produits" && $action == "ajout") {
     include('../Produits/AddProductForm.php');
   }
```

When i tried to navigate i come across this message:

> (404 Not Found : /Fournisseurs/index.php was not found on this
>   server).

I really don't see where is the problem. Do you have any tips or tutos  for solving this problem ?

Comment: you should be getting an undifined index `action ` error

Comment: Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. The code you have shown so far is not enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The 404 has nothing to do with the code - your code isn't running at all, because you're not accessing it. Once you manage to *find* your `index.php` file, you'll need to fix the fact that you're not setting `$action` anywhere - you're just changing `$page` to the action. None of the code will work.

Comment: Start with a **simple** "hello world" example first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i will try this tonight.
Sorry CBroe for the incorrect post.

Comment: hi, any progress ?

Answer (score 0):

`$page = $_GET['page'];
 $page = $_GET['action'];`

You are using the same variable name !

This looks better :P

`$page = basename($_GET['page']);
 $action = basename($_GET['action']);`

As for the 404...

`../` means parent folder, it seems the file you want to `include` is not located there. Be careful when using user input, validation / sanitization is mandatory

Comment: Okay ! i will check that. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
$page = $_GET['action'];
```

You set your variables with the same name. So the second `$page` is overwrite the first `$page`.

Comment: Okay. i undertstand. Thanks you !